# Getting Undifined by sending file to my Node.js Server from the frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, file-upload

I want to send an image file to my Backend node js Server. I worked with multer. I send the data as FormData, but I alway get undifiend as result. I am sorry for my noobCode:). I am a beginner.

here is my NODE.JS Server

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const multer = require('multer');
const app = express();
const upload = multer();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// const storage = multer.diskStorage({
//     destination: function(req, file, cb){
//         return cb(null, './Images');
//     },
//     filename: function(req, file, cb){
//         return cb(null, `${file.originalname}`);
//     }
// })

// const upload = multer({storage});

app.post('/newTweet',upload.single('file'),(request, response) => {
    console.log(request.files);
    console.log(request.body.file);
    response.json();
})

app.listen(8000, () => console.log("Listen to PORT 8000"))
```

here I load images

```js
const {setImageLoad} = useContext(contextForm);

    const handleImage = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      const file = new FormData();
      file.append('file', event.target.files!![0]);
      setImageLoad(file);
    }

  return (
    <div className='buttonIcon'>
        <label htmlFor="imageUpload"><BsFillImageFill/></label>
        <input id="imageUpload" type="file" name='uploadImageFile' onChange={handleImage} hidden/>
    </div>
```

i have worked with axios

```js
const headers = {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/newTweet', data,{headers});
```

data comes from here

```js
const [imageLoad, setImageLoad] = useState<FormData | undefined>()
const [newPost, setNewPost] = useState<{
    // profile: {username: string},
    // sentTo: string,
    // tweetContent:string,
    file: FormData | undefined
  } | null>(null);

const handleSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    
    const { tweetInput, selectSentTo } = event.currentTarget;
    const newPost = {
      // profile: { username: '' },
      // sentTo: selectSentTo.value,
      // tweetContent: tweetInput.value,
      file: imageLoad
    }

    setNewPost(newPost);
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(newPost !== null){
      apiPost(newPost);
    }
  },[newPost])
```

When I send data I get from the Server as result
'undifind' for console.log(request.files)

Comment: In axios you send `data`, but where is that variable populated? `handleImage` created a variable called `file`

Comment: sry for that. i add the missing code

Comment: data is newPost in my code

Comment: Your handler is `upload.single('file')` but the name of the input is `name='uploadImageFile'`, looks like these should match

Comment: change file input name attribute to "file" from 'uploadImageFile' , and access uploaded file from request.file instead of request.files because multer middleware using single function in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The state of `imageLoad` is already a `FormData`, so you only have to pass it like this `apiPost(imageLoad)`.

I suggest to call the API request inside `handleSubmit` method.

```
const handleSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  event.preventDefault()

  apiPost(imageLoad); // because imageLoad's type is FormData
}
```

##### Other Suggestion

Create a `input` state with normal `object` inside it, instead of using `FormData` immediately.

```
const [input, setInput] = useState({
  file: null as File | null,
  // username: '', ...and other inputs
});
```

To handle file select, do like below:

```
const handleImage = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setInput((oldState) => {
    return {
      ...oldState,
      file: event.target.files!![0] || null,
    };
  }); 
}
```

Then you can construct the `FormData` inside `handleSubmit` method

```
const handleSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  event.preventDefault()

  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', input.file);
  // data.append('username', input.username); ...and other inputs

  apiPost(data);
}
```